# Broken terminal when using team explorer everywhere command line client with vim for diff and merge

Tags: linux, vim, team-explorer-everywhere

When configuring the Team Explorer Everywhere Cross-Platform Command Line Client to use vim for diff and merge the terminal window the terminal gets broken when diffing or merging.

The terminal I am using is Cmder/ConEmu but the same symptoms also occur when using Putty.

In the terminal session with export=TF_DIFF_COMMAND='vimdiff %1 %2'

Calling

```
tf diff file1 file2
```

outputs `Vim:Warning:Input is not from terminal and Vim:Warning:Output is not from terminal`. Additionally it displays a vim window with two panes that is less than a quarter smaller than the size of terminal window. See the screenshot for an idea, however keep in mind that I removed some of the space to the right and to the bottom of the screen in order to keep the screenshot small. [Broken Vim Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dw3H.png)

The input is broken and the terminal never quite looks normally after quitting with Ctrl-C, the color scheme is broken.

How do I get the cross-platform command line client play nice with vim... or vim to play nice with the cross-platform command line client.

Comment: Try to check if the vimdiff command invoked by TEE CLC actually works in your terminal. If you look into the CLC log for the failed CLC command execution, you should see in it a record containing the string:

Comment: Try to check if the vimdiff command invoked by TEE CLC actually works in your terminal. If you look into the CLC log for the failed CLC command execution, you should see in it a record containing the string:

`INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.vc.diff.launch.DiffLauncher) Running CLC external diff like:`

It contain the actual command invoked by CLC via Java's `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` call. Try to copy and run this command in your terminal. I hope that could help to figure out what's going wrong with `tf diff`.

Comment: CLC logs can be found at:
Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Logs\teamexplorer-clc-*.log
Ubuntu:  ~/.microsoft/Team Foundation/4.0/Logs/teamexplorer-clc-*.log
Mac:     ~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Team Foundation/4.0/Logs/teamexplorer-clc-*.log